# EAGLE: Add a GND bus and a VCC bus to a proto board

Tags: eaglecad, prototyping

I am quite new in the Eagle world and I need help.
I have made a bunch of simple prototyping PCBs of different sizes as part of a custom library and now I want to add a GND bus and a VCC bus (like in the photo below).
[image]

I have done some research and I have found this project:

[enter link description here](http://playground.arduino.cc/Tutorials/Protoshield)

in which this guy is just using the routing command for connecting the holes in the GND bus. But I still have a couple of questions: 
1) Is this the best way for solving my issue?
2) It is possibile to do the routing directly in the library editor or I must do this in a new project?
3) Is there any difference between a route on the bottom layer or in the top layer for a 2 layers PCB?

Thank you for your time!

Answer (score 1):

I think that you are trying to make a ground and power planes. Just enclose the pins you want to connect in a polygon.

Have a look here how to use polygons:

[Sparkfun tutorial](https://learn.sparkfun.com/tutorials/using-eagle-board-layout/finishing-touches)

[Dangerous Prototypes tutorial](http://dangerousprototypes.com/blog/2012/07/18/eagle-polygons/)

Comment: thank you for your answer. I was thinking to add a GND plane and a VCC plane, but in this case I should make a 4 layers PCB instead of a 2 layers PCB, isn't true?.